# kube-dns stays in ContainerCreating status

Tags: dns, kubernetes, flannel

I have 5 machines running Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. I want to set them up as a Kubernetes Cluster. Iḿ trying to follow this [getting started guide](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/) where they're using `kubeadm`.

It all worked fine until step **3/4 Installing a pod network**. I've looked at there [addon page](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/addons/) to look for a pod network and chose the flannel overlay network. Iǘe copied the yaml file to the machine and executed:

```
root@up01:/home/up# kubectl apply -f flannel.yml
```

Which resulted in:

```
configmap "kube-flannel-cfg" created
daemonset "kube-flannel-ds" created
```

So i thought that it went ok, but when I display all the pod stuff:

```
root@up01:/etc/kubernetes/manifests# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                              READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   dummy-2088944543-d5f50            1/1       Running             0          50m
kube-system   etcd-up01                         1/1       Running             0          48m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-up01               1/1       Running             0          50m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-up01      1/1       Running             0          49m
kube-system   kube-discovery-1769846148-jvx53   1/1       Running             0          50m
kube-system   kube-dns-2924299975-prlgf         0/4       ContainerCreating   0          49m
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-jb1df             2/2       Running             0          32m
kube-system   kube-proxy-rtcht                  1/1       Running             0          49m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-up01               1/1       Running             0          49m
```

The problem is that the kube-dns keeps in the ContainerCreating state. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Take a peek into the POD logs for the container. Hopefully there will be a message indicating the issue.

Comment: use **kubectl describe pod** and **kubectl logs** to get more information.

Comment: I redid everything with weavenet and that was working, so there's that.

Comment: @Ravenix, I also switched to using weave, I was getting weird behaviour with flannel

Comment: Was anyone able to get it working with Flannel? I am seeing the same error even though i used --pod-network-cidr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very likely that you missed this critical piece of information from the guide:

> If you want to use flannel as the pod network, specify
>   --pod-network-cidr 10.244.0.0/16 if you’re using the daemonset manifest below.

If you omit this `kube-dns` will never leave the `ContainerCreating` STATUS.

Your `kubeadm init` command should be:

```
# kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr 10.244.0.0/16
```

and not

```
# kubeadm init
```

Comment: I have the same problem, and I didn't miss that information.

Comment: I intermittently hit this issue. If I mess around with it enough, it somehow fixes itself. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try restarting NetworkManager ...? it worked for me.. Plus, it also worked when I **also** disabled IPv6.